# Displaying specific text only in the airline of a given window

Tags: vimrc, vim-windows, plugin-airline, linux-ubuntu

Suppose that using `bufwinnr()` I find the windows number where a given buffer is being displayed to be `2`.

With that information, is there a way to display a specific string only in the `airline` status bar of that window, this is, of window `2`?

To be more specific, of course I did find examples of how to define airline parts for custom functions (see [Add custom section to airline](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15698/add-custom-section-to-airline)). However, what I could not do yet is to find how:

1) define an airline part for a constant string (for example stored in a dictionary). While the possibility of creating a part with a constant string is mentioned in `:h airline-advanced-customization`, there's no example of that and I can't seem find it easily.

2) I can't seem to find what would be the proper way to display specific strings in each window airline, according to the window number.

Any help or resource will be appreciated.

Comment: Youd need to have a function called in your statusline/airline/whatever. Idk how with airline but i do this in my own statusline : https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/471a6a82cfafb44f9ba3e6e5f35f96d13ec36e02/links/vim/vimrc#L70

Comment: Perhaps my comment makes less sense than i thought; why do you want a constant string for a buffer/window nr ?

Comment: I believe you can set window specific `section` variables, that will be shown instead of the global sections then.